# Enter command with each line from a file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to write a plugin that reads a file line by line and then enters a command in the console with each name as separate commands. This does contain code which relies on the Bukkit API, but it should be simple enough to figure out.

I am currently using a Scanner, but is a BufferedReader would be better, let me know. Currently, the scanner prints fine without the extra Bukkit code.

**Current code:**

```
public class FixWhitelist extends JavaPlugin {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FixWhitelist scanner = new FixWhitelist();
    scanner.readFile("white-list.txt");
}

public void readFile(String path) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path));
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String next = sc.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(next);
            Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "whitelist add" + next);
            Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(next + "added to the whitelist.");
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FixWhitelist.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

So, the question is, how can I have a command entered for each line of code in a file?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `BufferedReader` is 95% of the time better than `Scanner`

Comment: @Jason Should have clarified a bit more. My question is, how can I have a command entered for each line of code in a file?

Comment: @swiftsly without knowing how Bukkit works, isn't that what you have now? What is going wrong with your code now? Please provide details of what is failing and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Should the following line have a space after the "add":

```
Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "whitelist add " + next);
```